# selenium reload page source without refreshing the page (python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Problem:
I'm building a software using selenium which:

1. goes to a web page (a search page).
2. searches a term
3. the items get added to the search page dynamically
4. clicks on the first item
5. a pop up body happens with more info on that item which is a dynamic html added to the source
6. saves the info
7. Now I want to get out of that pop up, by clicking on an exit `<button>` using `driver.find_element_*`can't find the element without refreshing the page, because it was added to the page.

I've tried:

1. first try

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'the class of the element')))
and
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'class name')))
```

2. [second try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086773/selenium-webdriver-python-reload-html-without-refreshing-the-page) :

```
driver.page_source
```

3.[second try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519052/selenium-python-extract-dynamically-generated-html-after-submitting-form) :
combination of both

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME, 'the class of the element'))
driver.page_source
```

In the case of `wait().until()`; I don't find the button element even though I can see it in the browser, till I get timed out.

Thank you in advanced.

EDIT: the website is upwork.com job search

Comment: Can you provide us with the website in question?  It could be that your locator is incorrect.  Also it would be nice to see some actual code instead of empty functions calls.

Comment: "can't find the element without refreshing the page, because it was added to the page."  That is incorrect.  If the DOM is updated via javascript, you want to use a webdriverwait with an expected condition so that Selenium doesn't check the DOM during or before that update occurs.  (an implicit wait would also work but isn't 
 targetted to a specific condition.)

Comment: @AlfaQ I've edited the question, what is the solution?

Comment: @pcalkins I tried WebDriverWait, also tried time.sleep() non worked.

Comment: @AlfaQ what happened?